# Unable to run dbt in gitbash due to spaces in path

Tags: python, python-3.x, github, path, git-bash

I am trying to run dbt on gitbash, When i type dbt run and hit enter I get the following message

```
$ dbt run

bash: /c/Program Files (x86)/Python37-32/Scripts/dbt: c:\program: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I understand the spaces in the folder name `Program Files (x86)` could be the problem as gitbash doesn't like handling these.

I have tried moving Python37-32 outside of the folder to `/c/Python37-32` but then dbt is not found.

How am I able to resolve the issue

Comment: When I run this on the command line, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possibilities here:

- old versions of bash on windows just didn’t respect spaces in path names, in that case upgrading git/git bash will fix it
- the user has set their PATH without properly quoting the spaced strings. I doubt this, because it did find the full path to dbt.
- pip could have done a bad job rewriting the shebang line/it could have done a good job but git bash doesn’t support spaces in shebang lines. If this is the problem, then python -m dbt run would work, but dbt run wouldn’t. This is an old issue I vaguely remember! To fix it, you’d need to python -m pip -U pip setuptools and make sure your git bash is up to date.
  You can find out more about shebang rewriting in PEP394: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/
  Thanks Jake at Fishtown Analytics for the help on this.